# Joining two datasets into one query

Tags: mysql, sql, reporting-services

I am wanting to join two Datasets into one table.

We have branch codes which depict what data to produce. Is there a way I can join two branch data into one table?

```
select PartRefCategory
      , Company
      , BranchCode
      , convert(Date, DateOnly,3) As DatedOnly
      , (Quantity*UnitFinalPriceExcTax) As Sales 
from [dbo].[RPTSalesByTime] 
where 
     PartRefCategory NOT IN ('GIFT', 'POS', '') 
     AND BranchCode='BM8' 
     AND DateOnly>=DateAdd(DD, -6, @ByDate) 
     AND DateOnly<=@ByDate  
     AND NOT (quantity >'1000' or quantity <'-1000')
order by PartRefCategory, BranchCode
```

Comment: Your query only mentions one table.  I have no idea what you mean by "two Datasets into one table".  Sample data and desired results help.

Comment: This looks more like sql-server than MySQL

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [`IN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) expression to select from multiple `BranchCode` values. Change

```
BranchCode='BM8'
```

to (e.g.)

```
BranchCode IN ('BM8', 'ABC')
```